# Fail to build opencv jni example - OpenCV Sample - native-activity (undefined reference)

Tags: c++, opencv, android-ndk, java-native-interface, undefined-reference

I tried to build a OpenCV JNI Example (native-activity). I deleted most of the java stuff ( i only want to try some OpenCV JNI).

I added the paths in c/c++ general -> Paths and Symbol -> GNU C++ (sorry cant post screenshot)

```
${NDKROOT}/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.6/include
${NDKROOT}/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.6/libs/armeabi-v7a/include
${NDKROOT}/sources/android/native_app_glue
${NDKROOT}/platforms/android-19/arch-arm/usr/include
C:\Android\Development\OpenCV-2.4.7-android-sdk\sdk\native\jni\include
```

My **Android.mk** file:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

include C:/Android/Development/OpenCV-2.4.7-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk

LOCAL_MODULE    := native_activity
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := native.cpp
LOCAL_LDLIBS    += -lm -llog -landroid
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES += android_native_app_glue

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)


$(call import-module,android/native_app_glue)
```

**Applikation.mk:**

```
APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a
APP_STL := gnustl_static
APP_CPPFLAGS := -frtti -fexceptions
APP_PLATFORM := android-19
```

When i try to build the programm i get following error message:

```
C:\Android\Development\android-ndk-r9b\ndk-build.cmd 
Android NDK: WARNING: APP_PLATFORM android-19 is larger than android:minSdkVersion 9 in             ./AndroidManifest.xml    
[armeabi-v7a] Gdbserver      : [arm-linux-androideabi-4.6] libs/armeabi-v7a/gdbserver
[armeabi-v7a] Gdbsetup       : libs/armeabi-v7a/gdb.setup
[armeabi-v7a] SharedLibrary  : libnative_activity.so
C:/Android/Development/android-ndk-r9b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-    4.6/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-    androideabi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs-debug/native_activity/native.o: in     function cv::Mat::~Mat():C:/Android/Development/OpenCV-2.4.7-android-    sdk/sdk/native/jni/include/opencv2/core/mat.hpp:278: error: undefined reference to     'cv::fastFree(void*)'
C:/Android/Development/android-ndk-r9b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-    4.6/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-    androideabi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs-debug/native_activity/native.o: in     function cv::Mat::release():C:/Android/Development/OpenCV-2.4.7-android-    sdk/sdk/native/jni/include/opencv2/core/mat.hpp:367: error: undefined reference to     'cv::Mat::deallocate()'
C:/Android/Development/android-ndk-r9b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-    4.6/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-    androideabi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs-debug/native_activity/native.o: in     function android_main:jni/native.cpp:214: error: undefined reference to 'cv::getTickCount()'
C:/Android/Development/android-ndk-r9b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-    4.6/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs-debug/native_activity/native.o: in function android_main:jni/native.cpp:226: error: undefined reference to     'cv::putText(cv::Mat&, std::string const&, cv::Point_<int>, int, double,     cv::Scalar_<double>, int, int, bool)'
C:/Android/Development/android-ndk-r9b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-    androideabi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs-debug/native_activity/native.o: in     function android_main:jni/native.cpp:238: error: undefined reference to     'cv::getTickFrequency()'
C:/Android/Development/android-ndk-r9b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs-debug/native_activity/native.o: in function cv::Ptr<cv::VideoCapture>::release():C:/Android/Development/OpenCV-2.4.7-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/include/opencv2/core/operations.hpp:2604: error: undefined reference to 'cv::fastFree(void*)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make.exe: *** [obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libnative_activity.so] Error 1

**** Build Finished ****
```

**Verbose Output:**

```
Android NDK: WARNING: APP_PLATFORM android-19 is larger than android:minSdkVersi
on 9 in ./AndroidManifest.xml
del /f/q .\libs\armeabi-v7a\gdbserver   >NUL 2>NUL
del /f/q .\libs\armeabi-v7a\gdb.setup   >NUL 2>NUL
[armeabi-v7a] Gdbserver      : [arm-linux-androideabi-4.6] libs/armeabi-v7a/gdbs
erver
copy /b/y "C:\Android\Development\android-ndk-r9b\prebuilt\android-arm\gdbserver
\gdbserver" ".\libs\armeabi-v7a\gdbserver" > NUL
[armeabi-v7a] Gdbsetup       : libs/armeabi-v7a/gdb.setup
C:/Android/Development/android-ndk-r9b/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/echo.exe "set
 solib-search-path ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a" > ./libs/armeabi-v7a/gdb.setup
C:/Android/Development/android-ndk-r9b/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/echo.exe "dir
ectory C:/Android/Development/android-ndk-r9b/platforms/android-19/arch-arm/usr/
include C:/Android/Development/android-ndk-r9b/sources/android/native_app_glue C
:/Android/Development/android-ndk-r9b/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++ "C:/Android/
Development/OpenCV-2.4.7-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/include/opencv" "C:/Android/
Development/OpenCV-2.4.7-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/include" C:/Android/Developm
ent/android-ndk-r9b/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.6/include C:/Android/Develop
ment/android-ndk-r9b/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.6/libs/armeabi-v7a/include
C:/Android/Development/android-ndk-r9b/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.6/include
/backward" >> ./libs/armeabi-v7a/gdb.setup
[armeabi-v7a] SharedLibrary  : libnative_activity.so
C:/Android/Development/android-ndk-r9b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/preb
uilt/windows-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++ -Wl,-soname,libnative_activity
.so -shared --sysroot=C:/Android/Development/android-ndk-r9b/platforms/android-1
9/arch-arm ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs-debug/native_activity/native.o ./obj/loc
al/armeabi-v7a/libandroid_native_app_glue.a C:/Android/Development/android-ndk-r
9b/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.6/libs/armeabi-v7a/libgnustl_static.a -lgcc -
no-canonical-prefixes -march=armv7-a -Wl,--fix-cortex-a8  -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl
,-z,noexecstack -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now  -LC:/Android/Development/android-ndk-r9
b/platforms/android-19/arch-arm/usr/lib -lm -llog -landroid -llog -lc -lm -o ./o
bj/local/armeabi-v7a/libnative_activity.so
C:/Android/Development/android-ndk-r9b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/preb
uilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-lin
ux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs-debug/native_activity/na
tive.o: in function cv::Mat::~Mat():C:/Android/Development/OpenCV-2.4.7-android-
sdk/sdk/native/jni/include/opencv2/core/mat.hpp:278: error: undefined reference
to 'cv::fastFree(void*)'
C:/Android/Development/android-ndk-r9b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/preb
uilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-lin
ux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs-debug/native_activity/na
tive.o: in function cv::Mat::release():C:/Android/Development/OpenCV-2.4.7-andro
id-sdk/sdk/native/jni/include/opencv2/core/mat.hpp:367: error: undefined referen
ce to 'cv::Mat::deallocate()'
C:/Android/Development/android-ndk-r9b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/preb
uilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-lin
ux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs-debug/native_activity/na
tive.o: in function android_main:jni/native.cpp:214: error: undefined reference
to 'cv::getTickCount()'
C:/Android/Development/android-ndk-r9b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/preb
uilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-lin
ux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs-debug/native_activity/na
tive.o: in function android_main:jni/native.cpp:226: error: undefined reference
to 'cv::putText(cv::Mat&, std::string const&, cv::Point_<int>, int, double, cv::
Scalar_<double>, int, int, bool)'
C:/Android/Development/android-ndk-r9b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/preb
uilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-lin
ux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs-debug/native_activity/na
tive.o: in function android_main:jni/native.cpp:238: error: undefined reference
to 'cv::getTickFrequency()'
C:/Android/Development/android-ndk-r9b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/preb
uilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-lin
ux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs-debug/native_activity/na
tive.o: in function cv::Ptr<cv::VideoCapture>::release():C:/Android/Development/
OpenCV-2.4.7-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/include/opencv2/core/operations.hpp:2604
: error: undefined reference to 'cv::fastFree(void*)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make.exe: *** [obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libnative_activity.so] Error 1
```

when i remove calls to opencv functions the error disappears

to me it seems that the linker has a problem, but i dont know how i could fix it. 
thx for helping!

Answer (score 2):

try this code.

```
OPENCV_INSTALL_MODULES:=on
OPENCV_LIB_TYPE:=STATIC
include ../../sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk
```

I'm not sure it works, but it's worth to try.

Answer (score 1):

I want add some information from Sohyun's answer. Before you add code

```
OPENCV_INSTALL_MODULES:=on
OPENCV_LIB_TYPE:=STATIC
include ../../sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk
```

Please make sure your code is inside Opencv4android's folder. It means that you can find OpenCV.mk is inside ../../sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk. Of course you can change "../../sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk" to other path if you can find OpenCV.mk there.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue by reinstalling the [Cygwin](https://cygwin.com/) 
 and again build the project

Steps to build the project

**Setp 1.** Go to installed Cygwin dir.(usually it is on C:\cygwin) run the Cygwin.bat file

**Step 2.** in cygwing command window enter the following command

cd /cygdrive/YOUR PROJECT ROOT DIRECTORY

e.g  if your project is located at E:\Projects\NdkSample you have to enter

```
cd /cygdrive/e/Projects/NdkSample
```

**Step 3.** Now we need to run the ndk-build command,
open the NDK folder and run the ndk-build command in my case it is placed in E:\NDK\android-ndk-r10/ndk-build

Run the command as follows

```
/cygdrive/e/Android-SDK/Android/NDK/android-ndk-r10/ndk-build
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the similar error. In my case, i have downloaded the ndk for windows-x86_64. The paths were not right in some ndk calls. I have to rename the following folder:

1. ../android-nkd-r10b/prebuilt/android-arm64 --> ../android-nkd-r10b/prebuilt/android-arm
2. ../android-nkd-r10b/prebuilt/android-mips64 --> ../android-nkd-r10b/prebuilt/android-mips
3. ../android-nkd-r10b/prebuilt/android-x86_64 --> ../android-nkd-r10b/prebuilt/android-x86

You have to enable NDK-LOG to see the ndk-calls with the wrong paths!